# помогите доделать скрипт javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, chrome-extension

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
var element = elements[i];

for (var j = 0; j < element.childNodes.length; j++) {
    var node = element.childNodes[j];

    if (node.nodeType === 3) {
        var text = node.nodeValue;
        var replacedText = text.replace(/[word or phrase to replace 
 here]/gi, '[new word or phrase]');

        if (replacedText !== text) {

 element.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(replacedText),node);
        }
    }
 }
}
```

это скрипт должен выделать слова и заменять их другими(этот скрипт для расширения)помогите пожалуста переделать его так чтоб он несколько слов мог заменять

Comment: Лучше самому во всем разобраться!

Comment: спасибо кеп!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```js
var dictionary = {
  'hello': 'привет',
  'bye': 'пока',
  'fa': 'фа'
}
$('body').contents().each(function() {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(dictionary)) {
    var regex = new RegExp(key, "g");
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace(regex, value));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>hello hello</div>
<div><span>hellobye</span></div>
<div>
  <div>
    %hello_fafa%helloooo
  </div>
</div>
```